# Groovy - Unable to convert date string "2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400" to format required format

Tags: groovy

Below is my response code from a rest request

```
"createdDate" : "2012-02-27T18:10:28-0500",
"isDeleted" : "indeterminate",
"modifiedDate" : "2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400"
```

I am trying to convert a time stamp of format `2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400` to `MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm`

`-0400` indicates time zone

can anyone tell me how to convert this type of time stamp to required format?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Java 8 and Groovy 2.5,

```
java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse('2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX")
                        .format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm')
```

On Java 8 and an earlier version of Groovy,

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

OffsetDateTime.parse('2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400', DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX"))
              .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly understand problem You should prepare input timestamp and use `Date.parse`.

```
def input = '2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400'
pdata = input.replace("T", " ").substring(0, input.replace("T", " ").length() - 5)
def out = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", pdata).format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")

/* Output
println "Input date: " + input
println "Parse date: " + out

Input date: 2018-07-18T01:40:05-0400
Parse date: 07/18/2018 01:40
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to convert to required format not